# you don't know js book 'this' example

Tags: javascript

I am reading the book "you don't know js this & object" and I ran into below where they are explaining 'this'. Now, below example, I understand somewhat but I just do not understand what 'arguments' it is getting.

Is the word 'arguments' just some sort of place holder? I just tried it w/ argumentsX in place of arguments, and I get same console output of [ object Arguments]

If someone can point me to right direction, it will be greatly appreciated.

```
function foo(something) {
    console.log(this.a, something);
    return this.a + something;
}
undefined
// simple 'bind' helper
function bind(fn,obj) {
  return function() {
     return fn.apply(obj, arguments);
  };
}
undefined
var obj = {
   a: 2
};
undefined
var bar = bind(foo,obj);
undefined
bar
anonymous()
var b = bar(3);
2 3
undefined
console.log(b); 
5

///// Ok, I want to know what the arguments here is... so I run another one where I log to console what arguments is

// simple 'bind' helper
function bind(fn,obj) {
  return function() {
     console.log("YESS " + arguments);
     return fn.apply(obj, arguments);
  };
}
undefined
var obj = {
   a: 2
};
undefined
var NEWvariable  = bind(foo,obj);
undefined
var b = NEWvariable(3);
YESS [object Arguments]
2 3
undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, a function's signature is not checked when called, so you can call a function of any arity with any number of arguments. `arguments` is a reserved variable provided to you by the language that holds all the arguments sent to the closest function, so you can get them even if they do not appear in the function's signature:

```
js> function foo() {
    return arguments;
}
js> foo('a', 'b', 'c');
({0:"a", 1:"b", 2:"c"})
```